# Proper Format for a Switch/Case in a Class

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

Good Evening,

I created this method for a class. I used a switch/case to execute depending on the value of expression. I included an if-else method for each case. I do get an error on `case 1->` switch rules are a preview feature and are disabled by default. I attempted to add a `:` after `case 1` and `case 2`but my results reached high numbers for the sets. I changed the `:` to `->` and it worked appropriately. Now I am wondering if this was a proper way to set the case statements or should it be written differently.

```
   private void playGame()
{
    double winCheck = Math.random();

    switch (matchServer) {
        case 1 ->{
            if (winCheck <= player1WinProb)
                player1GamesWon++;
            else
                player2GamesWon++;
            matchServer = 2;
        }
        case 2 ->{
            if (winCheck <= player2WinProb)
                player2GamesWon++;
            else
                player1GamesWon++;
            matchServer = 1;
```

Comment: A normal switch statement with `:` would have been fine, but then you need a `break` at the end of each case to prevent falling through to the next case.

Comment: So the break would go under ```else``` or ``if``` and ```else```?

Comment: At the end of each case. So in your code, after `matchServer = 2;` and after `matchServer = 1;`

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am just now learning Java and never used ```->```  so I was curious as to why the normal ```case :``` didn't work.

Comment: Switch expressions (with `->`) are pretty new in Java, which is why someone just posted an answer who doesn't realise they're valid.

Answer (score 0):

A correct switch statement must use ':'

Also, 'break' is missing. This to avoid executing next cases.

You can add 'default' that means that case 1 and case 2 were not presented.

```
      switch (matchServer) {
        case 1:
            if (winCheck <= player1WinProb)
                player1GamesWon++;
            else
                player2GamesWon++;
            matchServer = 2;
            break;
        case 2: 
            if (winCheck <= player2WinProb)
                player2GamesWon++;
            else
                player1GamesWon++;
            matchServer = 1; 
            break;
        default:
            //If it was not 1 or 2
            //Printing the values can help
    }
```

Comment: Extra - Good programming practices - : Try to always use brackets, even when there is more than one line to be executed.

if(condition){
//code
}